# Lombok - java.lang.StackOverflowError: null on toString method

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, lombok

I have two classes `Product` and `Categorie`. When I would like to modify the list of products in categorie with `categoryRepository.save(c1)` as shown in the code below, this error occurs:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:449) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.sid.entities.Product.toString(Product.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.sid.entities.Categorie.toString(Categorie.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

---

```
@Document
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Categorie {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @DBRef
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();

@Document
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    @DBRef
    private Categorie categorie;

@Bean
    CommandLineRunner start(CategoryRepository categoryRepository, ProductRepository productRepository){

        return args -> {
            categoryRepository.deleteAll();
            Stream.of("c1 Ordinateur","c2 Imprimente").forEach(c->{
                categoryRepository.save(new Categorie(c.split(" ")[0],c.split(" ")[1],new ArrayList<>()));
            });
            categoryRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);

            productRepository.deleteAll();
            Categorie c1=categoryRepository.findById("c1").get();
            Stream.of("P1","P2","P3","P4").forEach(name->{
               Product p= productRepository.save(new Product(null,name,Math.random()*1000,c1));
               c1.getProducts().add(p);
               categoryRepository.save(c1);
            });

productRepository.findAll().forEach(p->{
                System.out.println(p.toString());
            });

        };
    }
```

Can anyone have an idea to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have a loop in your `toString()` method of Categorie and/or Product.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are having a circular reference in the `toString` method generated by Lombok.

- `Product` is referencing `Categorie` on `toString`, which is referencing `Product`, and so on

You could use the exclude a property `@ToString`, but it is going to be deprecated soon, so use the `@ToString.Exclude`:

```
@Document
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Product {
  ...

  @ToString.Exclude
  private Categorie categorie;

  ...
}

@Document
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Categorie {
  ...

  @ToString.Exclude
  private Collection<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();

  ...
}
```

Lombok refs [here](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ToString.html#exclude--) and [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString)

Comment: That helped, but I can't get the context. Could you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Would this solution need `@ToString.Exclude` in both places, or just one would be enough to break the circularity?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the `@ToString` annotation tells some tool you’re using (Lombok?) to generate a toString method that prints the values of all the fields. Each of the classes refer to the other: Product has a Categorie and Categorie has a list of Product instances. So when the toString implementation prints a Categorie, it calls toString on each Product, which then calls toString on its Categorie, etc. Since Product presumably refers to a Categorie which includes that Product in its products list, the toString calls bounce back and forth until the stack overflows. The solution is to avoid printing either Categorie,products or Product.categorie from the toString method. If you’re using Lombok, try annotating Categorie.products with `@ToString.Exclude`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Spring JPA implementation and entities were annotated with Lombok @Data which produces @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor together. However @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode annotations generate code with all the properties of an entity including **the collections** which usually reference other entities and other **One to One** relationship entities. This would result in circular references and also causes loading of Lazy collections as well (JPA loads One to Many and Many to Many in lazy fashion by default).

Adding `@ToString.Exclude` or `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` would result in cumbersome code and it is highly recommended to avoid using @Data or @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode on JPA entities. It is better to generate toString, equals, hashCode using IDEs and validate them (i.e., non-null vs null fields etc) before usage.