# There was an unexpected error type=Internal Server Error, status=500

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, lombok

Hello guys I get error 500 when I add the following line to my function :

```
Ticket ti = ticketRepository.findOneById(idtick);
```

Or this :

```
Ticket ti = ticketRepository.findById(idtick).get();
```

Both of them don't work, here is my function :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/tickets")
public String tickets(Model model, Long idp, 
        @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
        @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "8") int size,
        @RequestParam(name = "idtick", defaultValue = "0") Long idtick) {
    
    Ticket t = new Ticket();
    if(idtick!=0) {
        System.out.println("ID Ticket : "+idtick);
        Ticket ti = ticketRepository.findOneById(idtick);
        System.out.println(ti);
    }
    //Projection p = projectionRepository.findOneById(idp);
    model.addAttribute("ticket", t);
    Projection p = projectionRepository.findOneById(idp);
    Page<Ticket> tickets = ticketRepository.findByProjection(p, PageRequest.of(page, size));
    model.addAttribute("idprojection", idp);
    model.addAttribute("tickets", tickets);
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    model.addAttribute("films", tickets.getContent());
    model.addAttribute("pages", new int[tickets.getTotalPages()]);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    model.addAttribute("idtick", idtick);
    model.addAttribute("size", size);
    return "tickets";
}
```

Here is the Ticket class :

```
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(length=75)
    private String nomClient;
    private double prix;
    //@Column(unique = true, nullable=true)
    @Column(unique = false,nullable=true)
    private Integer codePayement;
    private boolean reserve;
    @ManyToOne
    private Place place;
    @ManyToOne
    private Projection projection;
}
```

And code of ticketRepository :

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin("*")
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Long> {
    public Ticket findOneById(Long id);
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251] at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251] at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251] at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.appendTo(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251] at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.appendTo(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251] at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251] at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]

Could someone tell me what's wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you autowiring `ticketRepository` in the constructor? What exception are you getting?

Comment: Can you show your Ticket class and ticketRepository ?

Comment: Yes i did @Authowired for ticketRepository, I will add code of ticket class and repository now thank you

Comment: What is the actual error? provide the logs.

Comment: I think it's an issue with the method signature in your repository class or a missing table name on the entity, what error message is being logged?

Comment: in the console there are the message ; Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: That's the error in the browser console, there should also be an error message in the server console which gives a java exception

Comment: In the console : java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal$BinaryToASCIIBuffer.appendTo(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.appendTo(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]...

Comment: Do the `Place` class or `Projection` class have `Ticket` as a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is symptomatic of an infinite loop. If the `Projection` or `Place` classes contain a `Ticket` element, then Lombok is running in to an infinite recursive loop when trying to generate methods for those classes. Check your code for other circular dependencies like such. See: [Lombok - java.lang.StackOverflowError: null on toString method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653734/lombok-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-on-tostring-method)

Comment: Yes both of them have a collection tickets, i will see thanks for your answer

Comment: There it is, the `toString` on `Ticket` calls the `toString` on `Place` and `Projection`, which both call the `toString` on `Ticket` which call the... stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Can u just Remove @Data, @NoArgConstrucor ,@AllArgConstructor from entity class and add things explicitly..  You have defined CrossOrigin at wrong place. Have you included spring-data-jpa-repository jar in your classpath ?. Is this Entity class getting scanned otherwise you have to explicitly make use of @EnableJpaReposiry. What is the SQL query getting generated due to JPA. Is your DB up? Run your application in debug mode, it would be much helpful.