# issue with @Aspectj logging if @EnableTransactionManagement added in sprig boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I tried to use `@Aspect` for **logging** all requests and responses the code is running fine and successful with a simple `spring boot` project with a common configuration and not have any init methods or DB call.

The below code is not working that includes init configuration and DB call for required data used `@EnableTransactionManagement` its getting Error while use `@Aspect` while running my application

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyContextClass implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

@Autowire
private MyServiceRepository myServiceRepo;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
          // Added Db call
          CommonUtils.setYears(myServiceRepo.getTotalYears());
    }
}
```

@Aspect logging code

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.*;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletResponse response;


@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)"
            + " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)"
            + " || within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void springBeanPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the
        // advices.
        log.info("springBeanPointcut");
    }

 /**
     * Pointcut that matches all Spring beans in the application's main packages.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(com.test.mypackage..*)")
    public void applicationPackagePointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the
        // advices.
        log.info("applicationPackagePointcut");
    }

 @Around("applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = methodSignature.getName();
        String methodParameterNames = methodSignature.getMethod().toString();
        if (request ! = null) {
            log.info(request.getRequestURL());
            log.info(request.getMethod());
        }
       if (response != null) {
            log.info(response.getRequestURL());
            log.info(response.getStatus());
        }
       final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
       stopWatch.start();
       Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
       stopWatch.stop();
}
```

this code build success. but when I run the application below error display the error in **setYears**

```
2021-05-07 20:14:58 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication-[SpringApplication.java:856]-Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:292)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.getRequestURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.opl.ans.config.utils.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
```

Is it the right way to do it? Are there any suggestions? Please help.

Comment: Within `logAround()` advice , modify the condition to `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null` instead of `request != null` . Also logging `response` before the control returns is not the correct approach.

Comment: Take a look at [HTTP Tracing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-http-tracing) and [Spring MVC Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-spring-mvc) as well.

Comment: If you do not have further questions and the issue is resolved , I can update the answer and you can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error stack the issue is that the `request` instance is invalid. I would guess that the `request` instance autowired to the `Aspect` could be stale or rather not assosicated with the current thread. This means that `request` instance is not null and the check within `logAround()` method gives unexepected results.

[RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestAttributes--) would return `null` if no request attributes are currently bound to the thread. Modifying the

`if (request ! = null) { ..}` check with `if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() ! = null) {..}` should fix the issue.

Also spring boot provides out of the box solutions to what you are currently attempting through AOP . Do check them out as well.

- [HTTP Tracing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-http-tracing)
- [Spring MVC Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-spring-mvc)

Comment: This solution is working but 1 issue is there if I transact from DB my entity class throws an error for `@ToString` lombok
```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:396)
        at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:1032)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
```

Comment: Please go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54654008/4214241)

Comment: I didnt realize you marked my answer as not an answer.  Your current issue is lombok related and nothing to do with Aspect or the solution I shared.

Comment: ok got it i will mark this as completed and create another for this Lombok related issue thanks

Comment: np. the solution to your issue is to exclude the toString() as pointed out in the answer I shared. good luck

Comment: thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653734/lombok-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-on-tostring-method?noredirect=1&lq=1 for reference

Comment: `Object result = joinPoint.proceed(); ` issue when return input stream any specific solution for this

Comment: @JaiminDarji what is the issue ?